# user validation error with mailgun connector loopback: email exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop, mailgun

I took the example project [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management/) and added the [loopback-connector-mailgun](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-connector-mailgun). I configured it like this:

In `datasources.json` added the following:

```
{
    "mailgun": {
        "connector": "loopback-connector-mailgun",
        "apikey": "[my api key here]",
        "domain": "[my domain here]"
    }
}
```

then in `model-config.json`:

```
{
    "Email": {
        "dataSource": "mailgun",
        "public": false
    }
}
```

When I register a client by doing a post in `localhost:3000/api/clients` the verification email is sent successfully but the server does not redirect me to the home page and after some time (it hangs for around 30 seconds) I get the following error:

```
{"name":"ValidationError","status":422,"message":"The `client` instance is not valid. Details: `email` Email already exists (value: \"a@b.com\") ...
```

The full stack is reported in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sanandrea/2a0b52cef35e8384bbbd169fdcaa655e).

My `client.js` function:

```
Client.afterRemote('create', function(context, client, next) {
    console.log('> client.afterRemote triggered');
    //console.log(typeof client);
    //var auth = dsConfig.emailDs.transports[0].auth;
    var options = {
        type: 'email',
        to: client.email,
        from: "noreply@loopback.com",
        subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.handlebars'),
        redirect: '/verified',
        user: client
    };

    client.verify(options, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err + 'Debug point 1');
        if (err) return next(err);

        console.log('> verification email sent:', response);

        context.res.render('response', {
            title: 'Signed up successfully',
            content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
            'before logging in.',
            redirectTo: '/',
            redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
        });
    });
});
```

The execution never reaches `Debug Point 1`. Thanks!

Comment: i think the email id you used was somehow added in the db. Try to clear the client datastore and retry this again.

Comment: No I am sure for this. It was not added in the db for sure. I am using the in memory db that is written to a file. I deleted the file and restarted the server before the sign-up

Comment: Did you define model name as `Client` or `client` ?

Comment: client.afterRemote is triggered, but is not hitting `Debug Point 1`